# LSTM Cell and Unit

Tags: lstm

Can anyone please make me understand the meaning of this "define the LSTM with 50 neurons in the first hidden layer". How are LSTM unit and cell different? What does the first argument in Keras model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]))) mean in context of cell and unit?

Comment: Since this is not a programming question, it might be more suitable to be posted in [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [blog](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) if you have not already looked at it. An LSTM cell is what maps the input (x) to output (h) and includes all the mathematical relations and gates to perform the mapping. The figure labeled "The repeating module in an LSTM contains four interacting layers." shows an LSTM cell.

An "LSTM with 50 neurons" or an "LSTM with 50 units" basically means that the dimension of the output vector, h, is 50.